# Внести данные в пользовательские поля в битрикс24

Tags: python, битрикс24

Есть телеграм-бот, который получает от пользователя два параметра - инн и номер карты. Нужно взять эти данные и засунуть в пользовательские поля в битриксе. Поля указаны в сделке, имеют тип строки. Видела решение на php, но не понимаю, как переделать его под питон. Вот код бота:

```
bot = telebot.TeleBot(os.getenv('TOKEN'))


@bot.message_handler(commands=["start"])
def hello(message):
   bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Введите ИНН')


@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def inn(message):
    global innn
    innn = message.text
    bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Введите номер счета')
    bot.register_next_step_handler(message, nomer)


def nomer(message):
    global number
    number = message.text
    bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, f'Вот твой номер {innn}')
```

Нужно вставить переменные innn и number

Answer (score 0):

Сначала нужно отказаться от global innn, number в пользу хранения значении в кэше. Можно использовать MemCache, Redis, также можно словарь с классом User внутри, где ключ это ТГ_id а innn, number его данные.

А работа с битриксом тоже можно использовать библиотеки готовые, или писать рест вручную.
https://opensourcelibs.com/lib/fast_bitrix24